# I want to create my first test using testcafe but getting error as below

Tags: powershell, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am writing my first test using testcafe in visual studio code but getting this error "import: The term '`import`' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
At line:1 char:1
+ import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
```

Comment: Bravo535, it would help if you can attach the "node: ", "testcafe: " and "npm: " version from your file `package.json`, inside your working folder?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you run your tests incorrectly. The error you provided is a Powershell error and it is not related to TestCafe.

The command should be `testcafe chrome test.js`.

Please share your test code and specify the way how you start your tests.

Please also take a look at the following article: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/